# how to configure network bridge for multiple ubuntu vms

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, ubuntu-server

I am very new to virtualization and and I have very basic understanding on networking. I have a dell server with good hardware configurations. I want to install few vms and I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on this host dell server. I want each VMs remotely accessed. I need these VMs with KVM. I have more than one physical servers and my ultimate goal is create vms and create K8 clusters across different physical servers. As I mentioned these servers have really good hardware configurations. I have created one vm on my first server and I created a network bridge using netplan. here is the config yaml file

```
    network:
      version: 2
      renderer: networkd
      ethernets:
        eno1:
          dhcp4: no
      bridges:
        br0:
          dhcp4: yes
          interfaces:
             - eno1
```

And I created my first vm with below commands

```
$ export ISO="/var/lib/libvirt/boot/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso" # Installation media
$ export NET="br0" # bridge name
$ export OS="ubuntu20.04" # os type
$ export VM_IMG="/var/lib/libvirt/images/ubuntu20.qcow2" # VM image on disk
$ sudo virt-install \
--virt-type=kvm \
--name dev01vm1 \
--ram 2048 \
--vcpus=2 \
--os-variant=${OS} \
--virt-type=kvm \
--hvm \
--cdrom=${ISO} \
--network=bridge=${NET},model=virtio \
--graphics vnc \
--disk path=${VM_IMG},size=500,bus=virtio,format=qcow2
```

I used VNC viewer to finish the installation and later used the vm ip address to connect and it seemed working. But I am not sure how do I create my second VM and subsequent VMs. I am confused with networking. Should I create separate network bridges for each VM or how do I do this? I thought my br0 will connect to eno1 NIC and all other VMs would be connected to this br0. But I am not sure now this whole thing works. Or how to do. A help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> thought my br0 will connect to eno1 NIC and all other VMs would be connected to this br0.

This is exactly how it works. Imagine the bridge being a virtual switch.

Comment: thank you very much. In that case all I needed is to execute the same virt command to create other vms ? except changing the name and disk values ?

Comment: Yes, that should work fine. For the ease of managing the VMs in the long-run, I can recommend running proxmox as a hypervisor.

Comment: thank you very mcuh!. Just installed proxmax.